# Spring cloud config fails to pick configuration from local file system

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to setup spring cloud config using local file system. However, I couldn't get it working.

Below is my application.properties file:

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-servers
server.port=8888
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=classpath:/config
```

[image]

Inside limits-service.properties, I have the following:

```
limits-service.minimum=4
limits-service.maximum=400
```

Once i run the server, i get the following. Please help in fixing it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a simple mistake of naming?

For example, your spring application name is `"limit-service"` while your property files are named `"limits-service"` and that might be why it is not reading them.

Answer (score 0):

yes above one it is working, spring.applicatiom.name must be equals to the properties file(Lets say uppercase must follow uppercase of properties file as well )